# how to put a different objects inside each array element of an array in php?

Tags: php

I have two arrays, e.g

```
$mainArray = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g');
```

$subArray = it contains an array of objects e.g

```
array( objec1, objec2, object3, object4) ...
```

within each of the objects, holds the value that matches one of the keys in the 
$mainArray.

my Question now is, how am i gonna match and put the correct objects to the mainArray, so that
it should appear like this e.g

```
$mainArray = array('a'=> array(object3,object2), 'b' => array(object4,object1));
```

Comment: Iterate over `$subArray` and fill the result array

Comment: which result array are you referring to ?

Comment: The one that you get as a result of the operation

Comment: How do you access this value that is stored in each object?  In other words, what test can be done to know that `object3` and `object2` belong to `a`?

Comment: @Crackertastic, need to iterate via foreach, each of the object in order to get the value like $val->keyOfMainArray , it seem complicated the way i see it

Comment: What do you mean by _hides the value that matches one of the keys in the `$mainArray`_? Do you mean "holds" rather than "hides"?

Comment: `$mainArray` is an indexed array, so its keys are 0, 1, 2, and so on. `a`, `b`, etc. are the values, not the keys.

Comment: i meant "holds" the value

Comment: @Barmar , I already changed the keys of the $mainArray by iterating throught it and doing something like `$mainArray[$blah->key] = $blah->letter; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `val` is your `object`'s property

```
$mainArray = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g');
$subArray  = array(...);
$result    = array();

foreach($subArray as $object) {
    $result[$object->val][] = $object;
}
```

Example result

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [val] => a
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [val] => a
                )

        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [val] => b
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($subArray as $obj) {
    if (!isset($result[$obj->keyOfMainArray])) {
        $result[$obj->keyOfMainArray] = array();
    }

    $result[$obj->keyOfMainArray][] = $obj;
}
```